# TestNG - How to call individual Test classes in MultipleTest Class

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am starting to use selenium webdriver with TestNG. I have created a multiple-test class which can run multiple tests, however, how do I call the other classes in each test block without copying the whole code over?

```
 public WebDriver driver;
  //Test 1
  @Test(priority = 0) //Set Priority of Test - Priority of test always starts from Zero
 public void one() {

  System.out.println("This is Test Case 1");
  }
//Test 2
 @Test(priority = 1) // Test priority 1
 public void Two(){

  System.out.println("This is Test Case 2");
  }
```

Would I need to create a function to call in each test block to run the other classes?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setUp()` method as described [here](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) to instantiate that class and keep it as an attribute.

> The method setUp() will be invoked after the test class has been built
>   and before any test method is run.

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class MyTest {

 private MyService myService;

 @BeforeClass
 public void setUp() {
      myService = new MyService();
 }

 @Test
 public void testSomething() {
      myService.doSomething();
 }
}
```